# Column math please help

Tags: arithmetic

If I'm adding the sum of

£100 +£320+£220+£20+£6+50p+20p+10p+5p+2p,

how would I write that using column math. Thanks

Comment: What is column math?

Comment: When you write the numbers in columns with hundreds tens and unites.google if not sure

Comment: @5xum the only addition that I know for this that uses columns, is this.$$\begin{align}&£100\\+&320\\+&£6\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes but I'm just not sure how to write the 50p,20p..... Not sure if it would be 0.50 etc.

Comment: Yes 100 pence are one pound. So it would be $0.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Since 1p = £0.01, you have

```
 100.00
+320.00
+220.00
+ 20.00
+  6.00
+  0.50
+  0.20
+  0.10
+  0.05
+  0.02
```

which adds up to $666.87$

Comment: Yes that the answer I was looking for,thank you very much.

Comment: Then consider accepting it so the matter can be considered solved.